# Error running '__rvm_make -j4', install ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rvm, puma

For two mounths I've been learning ruby and RoR. Everything was alright, but when I was created new project to another testing new skill, drama was start.

First, Rails could not start (openSSL and gem Puma 5.0.0 can't coworker). I was upgrade puma to 5.6 and tried to upgrade ruby from 3.0.0 to 3.1.2. I don't remember any mistakes anymore, but everything began destroyed step by step. I was start reinstall all what internet suggested.

So:

- Homebrew reinstall
- OpenSSL reinstall
- RVM reinstall
- PostgreSQL reinstall

In all this situation I lost all Ruby versions (i was R 2.7.0 and 3.0.0).

Now brew doctor say its all good.

But when I tried to install ruby, any command in terminal end error looks like below:

```
Error running '\__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/pokorny/.rvm/log/1689876336_ruby-3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I don't have any idea, what I can do more. Only "fix instruction" for this problem, what i found is for Mac m1 [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5152), but i have Mac air 2017.

To be more precision to my skills - I learning ruby for 2 months and this is time which I spend to start programing at all. So i really noobe. And sorry for my english - this is my new skill too

I'll be really grateful for any help.